# InlineScript helper does not always embed scripts in CDATA

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, xhtml

I have found out that:

```
$actionController->view->inlineScript()->appendScript("\n".'// script here'."\n");
```

Will not always embed the script in CDATA.

With an XHTML doctype you will get this output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

// script here

    //]]>
</script>
```

With a HTML doctype you will get:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<!--

// script here

    //-->
</script>
```

Is that actually correct? Shouldn't CDATA be used also in HTML?

Comment: It is correct. CDATA relates only to XML-family documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't CDATA be used also in HTML?

I was about to answer with a big fat "No!" ... but I'd have been wrong.

[HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/) is actually an [SGML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language) "application" (think "dialect").  SGML is the predecessor to XML.  SGML *does* have the `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` "marked section", but [things get a little complex](http://www.flightlab.com/~joe/sgml/cdata.html) when you try and define what it actually means.

[HTML 5 *keeps* the CDATA section syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#cdata-sections).  This surprised me a bit, as they'd gone out of their way to *divorce the HTML syntax* from SGML.  HTML 5 can be [represented either as it's own markup, or as XML](http://www.w3.org/QA/2008/01/html5-is-html-and-xml.html).

Now, all of this being said, you totally don't *need* to use CDATA sections in regular HTML documents, while you'll find yourself open to parse errors if you forget it in an XML document.

Comment: HTML 4 isn't SGML. It is a SGML application.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose it's worth trying to explain that.  Updated.

Comment: @Charles. The problem is I am getting validation errors because of inline javascript where I work with HTML strings. I want my HTML pages with inline javascript to validate. I cannot move all inline js code to external files because some of it is dynamically generated on the server.

Comment: @Richard, using what validation tool?  The insertion of comments *should* be enough to shut up most validators...

Comment: @Richard, could you update your post with a section of HTML produced by the tool that doesn't validate?  More out of curiosity than anything else.  I expect that you might want to dive into the `appendScript` method and see if it's possible to force a cdata section without putting it in there manually.